# how to add a image , song and artist name to a flash player using a xml file and AS3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

Hello i need to display a image on my flash file that is a music player so that i can place a music scoresheet. The player get songs from a xml file and here is my actionscript code:

```
var my_songs:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;

var my_sound:Sound;
var my_channel:SoundChannel;


var current_song:Number = 0;

var song_position:Number;
var song_paused:Boolean;
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("playlist.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void {
    var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

    my_songs = myXML.SONG;
    my_total = my_songs.length();

    //playSong(0);

    myXMLLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
    myXMLLoader = null;

}

function playSong(mySong:Number):void {
    var myTitle = my_songs[mySong].@TITLE;
    var myArtist = my_songs[mySong].@ARTIST;
    var myURL = my_songs[mySong].@URL;
    var myImageURL = my_songs[mySong].@Score;
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(myImageURL);
var img:Loader = new Loader();

img.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
img.load(url);

function loaded(event:Event):void
{
    event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

    var bitmap:Bitmap = event.target.content;
    addChild(bitmap);
}

    title_txt.text = myTitle;
    artist_txt.text = myArtist;

    if (my_channel) {
        my_channel.stop();
        my_channel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onNext);
    }

    my_sound = new Sound();
    my_sound.load(new URLRequest(myURL));
    my_channel = my_sound.play();
    my_channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onNext);
}

next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNext);
function onNext(e:Event):void {
    current_song++;
    if (current_song>=my_total) {
        current_song=0;
    }
    playSong(current_song);
}
prev_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPrev);
function onPrev(e:MouseEvent):void {
    current_song--;
    if (current_song<0) {
        current_song = my_total-1;
    }
    playSong(current_song);
}

pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPause);
function onPause(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (my_channel) {
        song_position = my_channel.position;
        my_channel.stop();
        song_paused=true;
    }
}
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlay);
function onPlay(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (song_paused) {
        my_channel = my_sound.play(song_position);
        song_paused=false;
    } else if (!my_channel) {
        playSong(current_song);
    }
}

menu_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.portugal.gov.pt"), "_blank");
}

fs_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullScreen); 

function fullScreen(event:MouseEvent):void {
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
}

import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;

var voltransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
sc.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG,changevol);

function changevol(event:SliderEvent):void{

voltransform.volume=sc.value;
SoundMixer.soundTransform=voltransform;
}
```

and the xml is the following:

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to load image then add this code:

```
var myImageURL = my_songs[mySong].@Score;
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(myImageURL);
var img:Loader = new Loader();

img.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
img.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
img.load(url);

function loaded(event:Event):void
{
    event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

    var bitmap:Bitmap = event.target.content;

    // if "score" is MovieClip and you want to put loaded image there
    score.addChild(bitmap);
}

function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
}
```

Comment: yes i need to add the image because the song name and artist name already display on each song txs for the answear tough i need a diferent image in each song do you know how can i do it?

Comment: Could you put that code in your playSong function? And it will load image when song starts.

Comment: updated the code on the post tough it doesnt work yet something is missing for sure

Comment: im trying to load it into a timeline movieclip named Score

Comment: Do you have Score MovieClip already created? If yes, change line to score.addChild(bitmap);

Comment: Maybe URL in XML is wrong. Add error listener, I updated the code.

Comment: Also it would be better if you name your Score attribute in XML lines to lets say "IMAGEURL", so it doesn't confuse you.